Limiting value of Stieltjes transform of sum of independent Wishart matrices
Let $n_1$, $n_2$, and $d$ positive integers tending to infinity such that $d/n_k \to \phi_k \in (0,\infty)$ and $n_1/(n_1+n_2) \to p \in (0,1)$. Let $X_k$ be an $n_k \times d$ random matrix with iid rows from $N(0,\Sigma_k)$ and consider the matrix $G_H(z) := (H -z I_d)^{-1}$, where $H := A+B$, $A:=X_1^\top X_1/n$, $B := X_2^\top X_2/n$, and $n := n_1+n_2$ and $z \in \mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R_+$. We make standard assumptions on $\Sigma_{1,2}$, like eigenvalues bounded away from $0$ and $\infty$, etc. It may also be assumed that $\Sigma_{1,2}$ are diagonal.

Question 1. What is the limiting value of $m_H(z) := (1/d)\operatorname{tr} G_H(z)$.

One would expect the above limit to satisfy some fixed-point equation. I stumbled on "Subordination for the sum of two random matrices
" https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.5818, but unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem because the "subordination functions" $\omega_A$ and $\omega_B$ therein are themselves defined in terms of $\operatorname{tr}A G_H(z)$ and $\operatorname{tr}B G_H(z)$, which are definitely more complicated than the sought-for $m_H(z)$.
Edit
Take $\Sigma_1 = \Sigma_2 = I_d$. Using the proposal here https://mathoverflow.net/a/157070/78539, the "R-transform" of the LSD of $A$ is $R_1(z) = p/(1-p\phi_1 z)$, and of $B$ is $R_2(z) = q/(1-q\phi_2 z)$ with $q:=1-p$. We deduce that
$$
R_H(z) = R_1(z) + R_2(z) = \frac{p}{1-p\phi_1 z} + \frac{q}{1-q\phi_2 z}.
$$
Also, it is well-known that $R(-m(z)) -1/m(z) = z$, and so
$$
\frac{p}{1+p\phi_1 m_H(z)} + \frac{q}{1+q\phi_2 m_H(z)} - \frac{1}{m_H(z)} = z.
$$

Question 2. Experts, please do you think the above is correct ? If so, can it be existended to the anisotropic case ?

It does look about right, because if we eliminate, say the first term on the right (which amounts to setting $p \to 0$), we have
$$
\frac{1}{1+\phi_2 m_B(z)} -\frac{1}{m_B(z)} = z,
$$
which is the well-known equation defining the Stieltjes transform of the Marchenko-Pastur law.
In the anisotropic case, it seems one should take
$$
R_k(z) = \frac{1}{d}\sum_{j=1}^d \frac{p_k\lambda_j^{(k)}}{1-p_k\phi_k \lambda_j^{(k)} z},
$$
where $(\lambda_k^{(j)})_{1 \le j \le d}$ are the eigenvalues of $\Sigma_k$, and continue as in the isotropic case.

Did you mean $d/n_k\to\phi_k$?

Yes, typo fixed. Thanks

Isn't it contained in the original paper by Marcenko and Pastur? A Marenko and L A Pastur 1967 Math. USSR Sb. 1 45. It handles random matrices of the form $A + X^TX$ provided $A$ is independent of $X$ with a limiting spectral distribution. In your case $A$ is also a covariance matrix that has a limiting spectral distribution by the same paper.

Thanks. Indeed, it seems Marchenko & Pastur (1967) indeed solved a general problem for which mine is an instance. See (1.14) of their paper https://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=sm&paperid=4101&option_lang=eng

Approach 1
As mentioned by user jlewk, Marchenko & Pastur (1967) indeed solved a general problem for which mine is an instance. Indeed, see (1.14) of their paper https://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=sm&paperid=4101&option_lang=eng
This, would give
$$
m_H(z) = m_A\left(-z+\int_0^\infty \frac{qt}{1+\phi_2qt}\mathrm d\nu_2(t)\right),
$$
where $\nu_k$ is the LSD of $\Sigma_k$, and $m_A(w)$ is a appropriate solution to the equation
$$
\frac{1}{m_A(w)} = -w +\int_0^\infty \frac{pt}{1+m_A(w)\phi_1 pt}\mathrm d\nu_1(t).
$$
Approach 2
Alternatively, Theorem 1 of this RMT monograph https://polaris.imag.fr/romain.couillet/docs/articles/det_eq_MAC.pdf gives
$$
\frac{1}{m_H(z)} = -z + \sum_k \int_0^\infty \frac{p_kt}{1+\phi_k e(z)p_kt}\mathrm d\nu_k(t),
$$
where $p_1:=p$, $p_2:=q$, and the function $e$ is defined to be the unique solution nonnegative to the equation
$$
\frac{1}{e(z)} = -z + \sum_k \int_0^\infty\frac{p_kt}{1+e(z)\phi_k p_kt}\mathrm d\nu_k(t).
$$
Thus, we must have $e(z) = m_H(z)$. We deduce that $m_H(z)$ is the unique nonnegative solution of
$$
\frac{1}{m_H(z)} = -z + \sum_k \int_0^\infty \frac{p_kt}{1+m_H(z)\phi_k p_k t}\mathrm d\nu_k(t).
$$
