# Determinant of arbitrary sum of positive semidefinite hermitian matrices

Tags: matrices, determinants

Suppose that $A_i$, $i=1,\ldots,m$ are positive semidefinite Hermitian $n\times n$ matrices, with $a_i^{(j)}$ being the $j$-th eigenvalue of $A_i$. Let $A_0=I$.

> **QUESTION.** Can we extend the result of M. Fiedler for $m=2$ (*Bounds for the Determinant of the Sum of Hermitian Matrices*, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.
>   **30** (1971) 27-31) to establish the bound
>   $$
> \det \sum_{i=0}^mA_i \le\max_{\sigma_0,\dots,\sigma_m\in S_n}\prod_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=0}^m a_i^{(\sigma_i(j))}\,\,?
> $$
>   ($S_n$ is the group of permutations of $n$ elements)

**Edit**: it should be noted $A_0$ is superfluous, since the statement would hold for singular matrices too. I didn't want the answers below to have to consider the additional case.

Comment: If you assume PSD, do you need the permutations on the RHS? The way you posed the problem (with permutations), you may drop the PSD condition.

Comment: This product does not depend on $\sigma$. Maybe, you need different permutations for different $i$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov That's what I had before, it seems to have been edited away. How can I revert?

Comment: @VF1 I do not know how to revert, now I edited once again. Hopefully it becomes ok.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Yes, this is what I had before. Thank you. Though of course the permutation $\sigma_0$ does not matter, nor wlog $\sigma_1$.

Comment: @VF1: Have you done some experiment to see whether your claim is true or not? For example, take $m=3$?

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan No, I have not done a large-scale experiment of this form (and I fear any counterexamples would be very hard to come by). I've posted my efforts as a partial answer below, hopefully they would justify why the conjecture is likely, at the very least.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan it also seems insight for $m=3$ can be found in [the reverse Minkowski determinant inequality](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/251646/reverse-minkowski-and-related-determinant-inequalities?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: The statement that you have should follow from Lidskii's theorem on eigenvalue majorization (however, I don't have time to check that right now).

Comment: @Suvrit I don't know what either of those things are, and I'd love to learn about them if you have time to write up an answer. Would my elementary proof not be sufficient here?

Comment: @VF1 I deleted my incorrect proof; the correct version of the proof uses the fact that $\lambda(A_1+\cdots+A_m)=D_1\lambda(A_1)+\cdots+D_m\lambda(A_m)$ for suitable doubly stochastic matrices, and then optimizing over these, but then it essentially reduces to your argument. Nice question though!

Comment: @Suvrit Ah, that's a shame, the tighter (incorrect) bound would've been a great find. I'll probably accept my own answer in a little bit if no one else has any other suggestions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The previous answer was incorrect due to an incorrect use of majorization. I decided to replace it by a correct version below for completeness, and to remedy the embarrassing error (though now the answer becomes essentially equivalent to the OPs own answer, so feel free to ignore!).
$\newcommand{\da}{\downarrow} \newcommand{\ua}{\uparrow} \newcommand{\nlsum}{\sum\nolimits}$

---

Recall that for Hermitian matrices $A$ and $B$, [Lidskii's](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/lidskii-inequality/) eigenvalue [majorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization) inequality implies that there exist doubly stochastic matrices $D_1$ and $D_2$ such that $\lambda(A+B)=D_1\lambda(A)+D_2\lambda(B)$.

Introduce the shorthand $a_{m+1}=\lambda(A_1+\cdots+A_m)$, and $a_j = \lambda(A_j)$ for $1\le j\le m$. Then, applying Lidskii's result repeatedly and noting that doubly stochastic matrices are closed under multiplication, it follows that there exist doubly stochastic matrices $D_1,\ldots,D_m$ such that
\begin{equation*}
  a_{m+1} = D_1a_1+\cdots+D_ma_m.
\end{equation*}

We wish to upper bound $\det(A_{m+1}):=\prod_i a_{m+1,i}$. Consider the function
\begin{equation*}
  f(D_1,\ldots,D_m) := \prod_i (D_1a_1+\cdots+D_ma_m)_i. % \le \left(\frac{\nlsum_i e_i^T(D_1a_1+\cdots+D_ma_m)}{n} \right)^n.
\end{equation*}

We now show that $f$ is maximized over permutation matrices. First, we make the change of variables $(D_l)_{ij}=D_{l,ij} = e^{u_{l,ij}}$. Moreover, we relax the doubly-stochastic constraints on each $D_l$ to
\begin{equation*}
  \Omega_n := \left\lbrace(U_1,\ldots,U_m) \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n \times n}\mid \nlsum_i e^{u_{l,ij}} \le 1,\ \forall i,\quad \nlsum_j e^{u_{l,ij}} \le 1,\forall j, \quad\text{for}\ 1 \le l \le m\right\rbrace.
\end{equation*}
Then, we consider the optimization problem
\begin{equation*}
  \sup_{(U_1,\ldots,U_m) \in \Omega_n}\quad g(U_1,\ldots,U_m) := \nlsum_{i=1}^n \log\left(\nlsum_{lj} a_{l,j}e^{u_{l,ij}}\right).
\end{equation*}
Since all the matrices $A_1,\ldots,A_m$ are positive definite, each $a_{l,j}\ge0$. Thus, $g$ is a convex function of the $U_i$. Hence its supremum will be at an extreme point of $\Omega_n$. These points correspond to the permutation matrices. Thus, mapping back to the $D_i$ space, we observe that $f$ will be maximized at permutation matrices.

This reasoning immediately yields the desired inequality:
\begin{equation*}
  \det(A_{m+1})=\det(A_1+\cdots+A_m) \le \sup_{\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_m \in S_n}\prod_{i=1}^n\left(\nlsum_{l=1}^m a_{l,\sigma_l(i)} \right).
\end{equation*}

Comment: Amazing, thanks. The constructive proof here is very helpful (and your tighter bound is much easier to compute, too!). Does your proof, along with mine, imply a theorem about combinatoric product optimization (that the maximum is reached in one of the $m$ arrangements you supplied)?

Comment: Not sure if the maximum is reached. Consider all diagonal matrices. Unless they are already permuted in the right way we may not get equality. However, the bound above does tell us one set of sufficient permutations to apply to the diagonal matrices to obtain equality and to saturate the inequality.

Comment: @Suvrit there may be a problem in the majorization below the Lemma. $x^\downarrow \succ y^\downarrow$ does not imply $x^\downarrow+z^\uparrow \succ y^\downarrow+z^\uparrow$. Eg. $x=(3,2,1)$, $y=(2,2,2)$, $z=(1,2,3)$.

Comment: @M.Lin You are right! I reveresed the argument when going through it. I think by introducing a suitable permutation on the involved vectors of eigenvalues one can recover the inductive step, but that will end up looking like VF's original proof. I will have to delete this answer and search for a fix!

Comment: Indeed, the argument begins to boil down to noting that: $\lambda(A_1+\cdots+A_m)=D_1\lambda(A_1)+\cdots+D_m\lambda(A_m)$, where each $D_i$ is a doubly stochastic matrix; after this optimizing over doubly stochastic matrices will lead to the original claim. So at this point, I'm going to delete my non-answer.

Comment: @Suvrit I believe that the end of your proof still requires the additional care does; namely $\partial \Sigma_n$ is not merely composed of the permutation points. However, at any lower-dimensional boundary the optimization function looks the same so we can apply your logic recursively. If we were to be very formal about this it would be tiresome to check this property; is there any way out?

Comment: @VF1 perhaps we may not need to go so far, but argue by contradiction because if the constraints in $\Omega_n$ are not satisfied with equality at an alleged optimum, then we should be able to perturb it while increasing the objective function (notice that the objective function is monotonic). This should then help complete the argument.

Answer (score 4):

**Thank you to @FedorPetrov for helping me complete the proof.**

Let $S=\sum_{i=0}^mA_i$, positive definite by its first term. Let its positive eigenvalues be $\lambda_i$ in any order, with corresponding eigenvectors $\textbf{v}_i$.

Let $\textbf{a}_i^{(j)}$ be the eigenvector of $A_i$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $a_i^{(j)}$. Since $\textbf{v}_k^\top\textbf{v}_k=1$, we have for any $k$:

$$
\textbf{v}_k^\top S\textbf{v}_k=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_i^{(j)}\langle \textbf{a}_i^{(j)},\textbf{v}_k\rangle^2
$$

From now on, iterations will implicitly on $i\in[m]$ and $j,k\in[n]$.

We continue:
$$
\det S = \prod_k\lambda_k=\prod_k\sum_{ij}a_i^{(j)}\langle \textbf{a}_i^{(j)},\textbf{v}_k\rangle^2
$$

Next for a fixed ${i_*}$, let us consider the following function on $n^2$ parameters $\{b_{jk}\}_{jk}$, represented as the matrix $B$:
$$
f_{i_*} (B)=\prod_k\left(c_k+\sum_ja_{i_*}^{(j)}b_{jk}\right)
$$
For some constants $c_k,a_{i_*}^{(j)}$ positive. To prove the conjecture it would suffice to show the lemma that:
$$
f_{i_*}(B)\le\max_{\sigma\in S_n}f_{i_*}(P_\sigma)
$$
Where again $S_n$ is the permutation group of $[n]$ and $P_\sigma$ is the corresponding permutation matrix. Applying the above bound $m$ times would actually yield something better than the conjecture (since our iterative bound is at most the global one).

Since $\left\{\textbf{v}_k\right\}_k$ form a full basis, expressing $\textbf{a}_i^{(j)}$ in those coordinates implies for any $j$:
$$\sum_k\langle \textbf{a}_{i_*}^{(j)},\textbf{v}_k\rangle ^2=1$$

Similarly for the basis $\left\{\textbf{a}_{i_*}^{(j)}\right\}_j$ and any $k$:
$$\sum_j\langle \textbf{a}_{i_*}^{(j)},\textbf{v}_k\rangle ^2=1$$

The above two statements imply $B$ with $b_{jk}=\langle\textbf{a}_{i_*}^{(j)},\textbf{v}_k\rangle ^2$ is bistochastic. By the Birkhoff–von Neumann Theorem, the set of bistochastic matrices is the convex hull of $C=\{P_\sigma|\sigma\in S_n\}$, where $P_\sigma$ is the permutation matrix of $\sigma$.

Then, since $f_{i_*}$ is convex (at least on $[0,1]^{n\times n}$, a superset of the domain of bistochastic matrices), the maximum value must be on $\partial\,\text{hull}(C)$. Since the face of a simplex is just a lower-dimensional one, we repeat this logic, eventually finding that the maximum must be located at one of the boundary points, some element in $C$.

Comment: Any bistochastic matrix is indeed a convex combination of permutation matrices. It is Birkhoff theorem.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Ah, excellent, thank you again. I think with your modification, this brings the proof nearer to completion. Unfortunately, it is only $B^2$ that is bistochastic, not $B$. I think there may be a workaround.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Ah, I made a typo - you are correct, this completes the proof!